# Elementary question | Possible ways to divide 8 pens amongst 4 girls?

Tags: combinatorics

So I have a simple  combinatorics question which I am trying to explain to students I am tutoring but I am not sure which formula is used in the solution and how to explain it to my mentees.

> If 8 pens are to be divided amongst 4 girls:
>
> (a) How many divisions are possible?
>
> (b) What if we gave each girl at least one pen?

**Solution a**
\begin{align}
\frac{11!}{8!3!}
\end{align}

**Solution b**

\begin{align}
\frac{7!}{4!3!}
\end{align}

Could you please show where the solution comes from? I think it is of the form:

\begin{align}
\frac{(n + r - 1)!}{n!(r-1)!},
\end{align}

but I could be wrong.

Comment: See [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: Thanks @lulu that answers my question. I am not sure if I should delete this question since its been down voted. I know its trial but It is a genuine question and I appreciate your answer.

Comment: This is a combinatorics question, not a probability question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for clarifying that. It's for an introduction to probability class hence I just assumed it would fall under that. I edited it.

Comment: There is an implicit assumption here that the pens are identical, in which case the answers you have stated are correct.  If the pens were distinct, there would be $4^8$ ways to distribute them without restriction and $4^8 - \binom{4}{1}3^8 + \binom{4}{2}2^8 - \binom{4}{3}1^8$ ways to distribute them so that each girl received at least one pen.  The last answer comes from applying the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have $8$ pens and $3$ sticks - this is $11$ objects in total.

The total number of ways to arrange this (non-distinct) objects is given by $\binom{11}{3}$.

So what? Well, if you read an arrangement from left to right, give all the pens to the left of the first stick to girl 1. Give the pens between stick 1 and stick 2 to girl 2, between stick 2 and stick 3 to girl 3 and the pens to the right of stick 3 to girl 4.

If there are no pens in any of the partitions, the corresponding girl gets no pens.

As each combination is different, this is then the number of ways to split $8$ pens into $4$ girls.

If every girl is to receive at least one pen, do this first, and so now there are only $7$ pens remaining, and so we use $\binom{7}{3}$ instead to do the same trick.